# JavaScript: canvas touch events

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying in vain to make my canvas tactile: I have added the touch events and `e.preventdefault` (to avoid scrolling), but nothing appears on my canvas (the method works perfectly on the desktop).

When I make a test using the Google Chrome responsive tools, nothing appears on the canvas (I just can see that the array ongoingTouches is filled ... here is my code (what did I miss?):

```js
class Canvas {
    constructor(CanvasId) {
        this.CanvasId = CanvasId;
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(this.CanvasId);
        this.enregistrer = document.getElementById(this.saveId);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.radius = 2;
        this.dragging = false; // True when clicking on the mouse
        this.lineWidth = this.radius*2;
        this.initCanvas();
        this.initEvent();
    }

    initCanvas() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, 250, 250); // canvas vierge
        this.context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    }

    colorForTouch(touch) {
        var id = touch.identifier;
        id = id.toString(16); // Make it a hexadecimal digit
        return "#" + id + id + id;
    }

    ongoingTouchIndexById(idToFind) {
        for (var i=0; i<this.ongoingTouches.length; i++) {
            var id = this.ongoingTouches[i].identifier;
            if (id == idToFind) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1; // Not found
    }

    handleStart(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touches = evt.changedTouches;
        for (var i=0; i< touches.length; i++) {
            this.ongoingTouches.push(touches[i]);
            var color = this.colorForTouch(touches[i]);
            this.context.fillStyle = color;

            this.context.fillRect(touches[i].pageX-2, touches[i].pageY-2, 4, 4);
            this.compteur++;
            this.enregistrer.disabled = false;
        }
    }

    handleMove(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touches = e.changedTouches;
        this.context.lineWidth = 4;
        for (var i=0; i<touches.length; i++) {
            var color = this.colorForTouch(touches[i]);
            var idx = this.ongoingTouchIndexById(touches[i].identifier);
            this.context.fillStyle = color;
            this.context.beginPath();
            this.context.moveTo(this.ongoingTouches[idx].pageX, this.ongoingTouches[idx].pageY);
            this.context.lineTo(touches[i].pageX, touches[i].pageY);
            this.context.closePath();
            this.context.stroke();
            this.ongoingTouches.splice(idx, 1, touches[i]); // Swap in the new touch record
        }
    }

    handleEnd(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touches = e.changedTouches;
        this.context.lineWidth = 4;
        for (var i=0; i<touches.length; i++) {
            var color = this.colorForTouch(touches[i]);
            var idx = this.ongoingTouchIndexById(touches[i].identifier);
            this.context.fillStyle = color;
            this.context.beginPath();
            this.context.moveTo(this.ongoingTouches[i].pageX, this.ongoingTouches[i].pageY);
            this.context.lineTo(touches[i].pageX, touches[i].pageY);
            this.ongoingTouches.splice(i, 1); // Remove it; we're done
        }
    }

    initEvent() {
        this.canvas.addEventListener("touchstart",this.handleStart, false);
        this.canvas.addEventListener("touchmove",this.handleMove, false);
        this.canvas.addEventListener("touchleave", this.handleEnd, false);
        this.canvas.addEventListener("touchend", this.handleEnd, false);
    }
```

Comment: In the sample code, an ending `}` seems to be missing.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found an easy solution. This is the code I added:

```js
getTouchPosition(e) {
    var rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(e);
    return {
        x: (e.touches['0'].clientX - rect.left) * (this.canvas.width / rect.width),
        y: (e.touches['0'].clientY - rect.top) * (this.canvas.height / rect.height)
    }
}


handleStart(e) {
    var touchesPosition = this.getTouchPosition(e);
    this.dragging = true;
    this.context.moveTo(touchesPosition.x, touchesPosition.y);
    this.context.beginPath();
    e.preventDefault();
}


handleMove(e) {
    var touchesPosition = this.getTouchPosition(e);
    this.context.lineTo(touchesPosition.x, touchesPosition.y)
    this.context.stroke();
    this.compteur++;
    e.preventDefault();
}


handleEnd(e) {
    this.dragging = false; // Stop le tracÃ©
    e.preventDefault();
}


this.canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    this.handleStart(e);
}.bind(this));


this.canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
    this.handleMove(e);
    this.enregistrer.disabled = false;
}.bind(this));


this.canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
    this.handleEnd(e);
}.bind(this));
```